# JWT Token using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if it would be possible to grab JWT Tokens from Firebase using Dart in Flutter, it seems that I can grab the UserID but can't seem to find a way to get JWT Tokens.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the JWT for the current user by [calling `getIdToken()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/getIdToken.html) on the user object.